# classnotfoundexception javax/mail/MessagingException

Tags: jakarta-mail, classnotfoundexception

I am getting the classnotfoundexception javax/mail/MessagingException using Eclipse/Jetty.

I have added activation.jar, javax.mail-1.5.3.jar, and javaee.jar to my Java build path to my lib folder and war/web-inf/lib folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I was trying to execute the code on the client.  Once I moved the code to the server it worked great and javaee.jar wasn't required.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add those jar file in classpath, go to your project build path and there you can see classpath tab, find your jar's and select them and save, should work after that.

Comment: Yes I did it.  Eclipse refers to the class path as the build path.  I should have been more explicit. Thanks.